# How to generate swagger specification file (json) from python using annotations in code?

Tags: python, documentation, tornado, swagger-2.0

**Problem statement**: I want to  automate the generation of machine and human readable specifications for JSON APIs so anyone can visualize and interact with our API. 
One of the feasible solution is to use [OpenAPISpecification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) (fka swagger). I was not able to find a comprehensible guide to use swagger particularly with tornado, so my questions are:

1. How can I **auto** generate swagger specification file from annotations in python code?
2. I'm also using [JSON schemas](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/) for input validation, how can I integrate these with swagger specification.

My API is written in python 2.7.11 with tornado 4.3.
Please do suggest if you have any other suggestion than using swagger too.

Update: [Apispec](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec) is an interesting start but it cannot be used with JSON schemas as of now, so doesn't answer my question [entirely](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec/issues/154).

Comment: just checking if you find any solution for this? i also have to do similar thing. Wondering if there is a way to generate the swagger file, by writing some kind of parser or something in python

Answer (score 1):

we recently had this requirement at work.  We made our own generator which generates OpenAPI 3.0 api spec from Google style docstrings.  You just need to decorate handlers and model classes.  For more info:  https://pypi.org/project/tornado-swirl/  -- still a work in progress though but we are actively working on it.

```
import tornado.web
import tornado_swirl as swirl

@swirl.restapi('/item/(?P<itemid>\d+)')
class ItemHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, itemid):
        """Get Item data.

        Gets Item data from database.

        Path Parameter:
            itemid (int) -- The item id
        """
        pass

@swirl.schema
class User(object):
    """This is the user class

    Your usual long description.

    Properties:
        name (string) -- required.  Name of user
        age (int) -- Age of user

    """
    pass



def make_app():
    return swirl.Application(swirl.api_routes())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin that is compatible with python2.7. You can install it directly using `pip install -U tornado-rest-swagger`. It uses the syntax of openapi3.0. Here is an example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado_swagger.components import components
from tornado_swagger.setup import setup_swagger


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def data_received(self, chunk):
        pass


class PostsHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        """
        ---
        tags:
          - Posts
        summary: List posts
        description: List all posts in feed
        operationId: getPost
        responses:
            '200':
              description: A list of users
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfPostModel'
                application/xml:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfPostModel'
                text/plain:
                  schema:
                    type: string
        """

    def post(self):
        """
        ---
        tags:
          - Posts
        summary: Add a new Post to the blog
        operationId: addPost
        requestBody:
          description: Post object that needs to be added to the blog
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
          required: true
        responses:
          '405':
            description: Invalid input
            content: {}
        security:
          - petstore_auth:
              - 'write:pets'
              - 'read:pets'
        """


class PostsDetailsHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, posts_id):
        """
        ---
        tags:
          - Posts
        summary: Find Post by ID
        description: Returns a single post
        operationId: getPostById
        parameters:
          - name: post_id
            in: path
            description: ID of post to return
            required: true
            schema:
              type: integer
              format: int64
        responses:
          '200':
            description: successful operation
            content:
              application/xml:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
          '400':
            description: Invalid ID supplied
            content: {}
          '404':
            description: Pet not found
            content: {}
        security:
          - api_key: []
        """

    def patch(self, posts_id):
        """
        ---
        tags:
          - Posts
        summary: Find Post by ID
        description: Returns a single post
        operationId: getPostById
        parameters:
          - name: post_id
            in: path
            description: ID of post to return
            required: true
            schema:
              type: integer
              format: int64
        requestBody:
          description: Post object that needs to be added to the blog
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
          required: true
        responses:
          '400':
            description: Invalid ID supplied
            content: {}
          '404':
            description: Pet not found
            content: {}
        security:
          - api_key: []
        """

    def delete(self, posts_id):
        """
        ---
        tags:
          - Posts
        summary: Delete Post by ID
        description: Returns a single post
        operationId: getPostById
        parameters:
          - name: post_id
            in: path
            description: ID of post to return
            required: true
            schema:
              type: integer
              format: int64
        responses:
          '200':
            description: successful operation
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  type: object
                  description: Post model representation
                  properties:
                    id:
                      type: integer
                      format: int64
                    title:
                      type: string
                    text:
                      type: string
                    is_visible:
                      type: boolean
                      default: true
          '400':
            description: Invalid ID supplied
            content: {}
          '404':
            description: Pet not found
            content: {}
        """


@components.schemas.register
class PostModel(object):
    """
    ---
    type: object
    description: Post model representation
    properties:
        id:
            type: integer
            format: int64
        title:
            type: string
        text:
            type: string
        is_visible:
            type: boolean
            default: true
    """


@components.schemas.register
class ArrayOfPostModel(object):
    """
    ---
    type: array
    description: Array of Post model representation
    items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/PostModel'
    """


@components.security_schemes.register
class JWTToken(object):
    """
    ---
    type: http
    scheme: bearer
    bearerFormat: JWT
    """


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    _routes = [tornado.web.url(r"/api/posts", PostsHandler), tornado.web.url(r"/api/posts/(\w+)", PostsDetailsHandler)]

    def __init__(self):
        settings = {"debug": True}

        setup_swagger(
            self._routes,
            swagger_url="/doc",
            description="",
            api_version="1.0.0",
            title="Journal API",
            contact=dict(name="test", email="test@domain.com", url="https://www.cluas.me"),
        )
        super(Application, self).__init__(self._routes, **settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.define("port", default="8080", help="Port to listen on")
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app = Application()
    app.listen(port=8080)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

f your function is a decorator and uses python2.7, you can try wrapping your decorator with a [decorator](https://github.com/micheles/decorator) (`pip install decorator`)so you can get the correct behavior.

Comment: If you can post the same answer to two questions without having to change a single bit, the questions are probably duplicates. Do not post the same answer multiple times.